# How to parse own language to java file

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I am trying to make a java program that parse my own format to java file. For example, when I write a file with

```
show("Hello World");
```

and save this file as hello.[my_own_extension] and read from my program and export something like that,

```
class Hello {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println( "Hello World");
  }
}
```

I read many articles on web. But they are writing about javacc, compiling technique, lexical analysis and so on. But the only things I want to do is
1. Read the file
2. Test whether the file is match with my rules
3. write(output) .java file and .class file
How can I do this?
Can I do that with the following way,
1. use java.io or java.nio packages (to read or write file)
2. write my own logic for my rules (may be simple java code)
I do not mean, I am creating a new programming language and I am not a java guru. I just want to know.

Comment: You would read the file just like you read a text file. Let's say you file ext is .me2 then you would use "theNameOfYourFile.me2" when reading the file.

Comment: It sounds like you want to build a parser/compiler of some sort.  This might be too broad a question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can I write my own program to create a parser without using any tools such as javcc?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible.  I've had to do it--back in college, I took a series in compiler construction, and we had to write our own parser (plus generate code).  The whole series was three courses that took a year.  We won't be able to squeeze a year's worth of learning into one StackOverflow answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I write my own program to create a parser without using any tools such as javcc?

Yes you can<sup>1</sup>.  Indeed, in my honors course (nearly 40 years ago) the lecturer set us an assignment to implement a recursive descent parser for Pascal from scratch.  IIRC it was a lot of work.

But if you are serious about it, a parser generator will give you a much better parser for a lot less effort.

The exercise I mentioned above was part of a ~10 week "honors" level course on Compiler Construction.  So don't imagine that you have to read / learn less to implement a parser from scratch than you need to read / learn to use javacc.

---

<sup>1 - Any task that a computer can do, a human being ... or large enough team of human beings ... can do as well.  It might take an unrealistically long time, and cost an unrealistic amount of money, but it is possible.  In **this** case, it is a realistic task.  This is how all parsers were created before the [first parser generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_compiler_construction#Parser_generators) were invented.  Indeed, even after that it took a long time for PGs to catch on.</sup>

Comment: Learning javacc or a parser generator is more appropriate than creating from scratch?

Comment: It depends on what your goal is ...